# How to upload a C# project to Github without visual studio

Tags: c#, github

I would like to know  How to upload a C# project  to Github without visual studio?
What do i need and how would I do it?

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because similar questions have already been asked on stackoverflow  with good answers there.

Comment: You can close. I got my answer. Now I understand that with this sync tool  it does not matter in what language I develop, ill be able to upload to github. The questions is not about a programming issue its about software developer tools!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow Github's guide to [getting your project on Github](https://guides.github.com/introduction/getting-your-project-on-github/).

Generically, there are several options, assuming you've installed git and possibly a git-related utility:

- via commandline
- via a UI

See this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12799719/how-to-upload-a-project-to-github) for more info.